# How to Create Custom Compass for google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am using custom compass google map in my app Please let to know how to set functionality to compass to rotate as per map rotation.

Answer (score 1):

map does not give this functionality that easily replace compass with your custom image.

But one way is disable default compass via setCompassEnabled and draw your own. Use sensors to make it point in the right direction.

you can use following example to point right direction. see below link.
[custom compass with sensor manager](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/08/simple-compass-sensormanager-and.html)

Comment: sorry i coudn't understand that link functionality can you please say

Comment: you would have to create a custom compass using sensor manager using the link provided and disable the default one provided by maps v2

Comment: k is it possible to set custom compass through OnCameraChangeListener

Comment: mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        // check cameraPosition if bearing is north and tilt is zero
        // if true, set tilt to 60

}

Comment: how to check bearing is at north